# Error : 10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None

Tags: python, aws, network

We are getting this error

Error: - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

While we are trying to establish connection to login.salesforce.com and fetching bulk data asynchronously

And AWS Host Close the process because it has been idle for too long and Code tries to reused the connection when asynchronous process is completed

Script Working fine on local getting this error only on VM (AWS) .which indicates problem with the remote (Server) as it says the Server is closing

As a work around we have tried

to define function(batch_is_not_complete) which checks either asynchronous batch is completed or not if not completed it will log status of all the batches and also call method keep_alive() To check connectivity of these URLs and log status code on every 60 second

Expecting Host will not treat transaction as idle and it'll maintain connectivity

But still we are getting same issue.

Does someone have an idea how I can resolve this issue?